# Combining two sinusoids with differing amplitudes and similar frequencies

Tags: trigonometry

This seems likes a super simple problem, but I cannot figure out how to combine these two sinusoids.

$$x(t)=-3*\cos(2\pi f_0 t)+4\sin(2 \pi f_0 t)$$

I tried using the first two relationships mentioned [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry), but I ended up back where I started.

What identity or property can I use here to combine this two sinusoids into one?

Comment: I think the inverse of FFT may help but I'm basically a rank beginner there.

Comment: How about simply dividing and multiplying by $5$? And have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the two relationships I found on wikipedia.

$$\cos x=\frac {e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2},\space
\sin x= \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$-3*\cos(2\pi f_0 t)=-3(\frac {e^{i2 \pi f_0 t}+e^{-i2 \pi f_0 t}}{2})$$

$$4\sin(2 \pi f_0 t)=4(\frac {e^{i2 \pi f_0 t}-e^{-i2 \pi f_0 t}}{2})$$

$$x(t)=-3(\frac {e^{i2 \pi f_0 t}+e^{-i2 \pi f_0 t}}{2})+4(\frac {e^{i2 \pi f_0 t}-e^{-i2 \pi f_0 t}}{2})$$

$$=-\frac{3}{2}e^{i2 \pi f_0 t}-\frac{3}{2}e^{-i2 \pi f_0 t}-2ie^{i2 \pi f_0 t}+2ie^{-i2 \pi f_0 t}$$

$$=e^{i2 \pi f_0 t}(-\frac{3}{2}-2i)+e^{-i2 \pi f_0 t}(-\frac{3}{2}+2i)$$

$$a+ib=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i \arctan{(\frac{b}{a})}}$$
$$|x(t)|=\sqrt{({-\frac{3}{2}})^2+(-2)^2}=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$\angle x(t)= \arctan{\big(-\frac{2}{-\frac{3}{2}}\big)}=\arctan{\big(\frac{4}{3}\big)}$$

$$x(t)=\frac{5}{2}\large(e^{i2 \pi f_0 t+\arctan{(\frac{4}{3})}}+e^{-i2 \pi f_0 t+\arctan{(\frac{-4}{3})}}\large)$$

$$x(t)=\frac{5}{2}[ \cos({2 \pi f_0 t+\arctan{(\frac{4}{3})}}) +j\sin({2 \pi f_0 t+\arctan{(\frac{4}{3})}}) + \cos({2 \pi f_0 t+\arctan{(\frac{4}{3})}})-  j\sin({2 \pi f_0 t+\arctan{(\frac{4}{3})}})]$$

$$\boxed{x(t)=5\cos({2 \pi f_0 t+\arctan{(\frac{4}{3})}})}$$